# Mongoose populate documents with specific property value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, coffeescript, mongoose-populate

I need to populate documents that have a property Type with value "recurring_expense"(every of these docs has that prop.), but my code pass every object of found. I'm use the $match operator, but nothing happens.
Here is my code:

```
Tenancy.populate properties, [
  {path: 'reminder.referrer', model: 'ScheduledPayment', match: {type: 'recurring_expense'}}
], (err, properties) ->
  cb err, properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $in instead of match:

```
Tenancy.populate properties, [
  {path: 'reminder.referrer', model: 'ScheduledPayment', {type { $in: ['recurring_expense']}}
], (err, properties) ->
  cb err, properties
```

For more clarification you can go to the following link: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query